# addition of specific element of array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

this is my session array of cart application in laravel 6

```
[cartS] => Array ( 

[0] => Array ( 
    [pid] => 3 
    [pname] => Watch 
    [price] => 500
    [qnty] => 5 
    [pimg] => 3.jpg 
    ) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [pid] => 1 
    [pname] => Mobile case
    [price] => 200 
    [qnty] => 3 
    [pimg] => 1.jpg 
    ) 
)
```

i have a table in checkout page
i am doing foreach loop so i can access `$key => $value` of session array

```
product    quantity   total_price
-------    --------   ------------
item1      2           100 ( here 100 is multipication of price and qunatity)
item2      4           200
item3      2           200
-------------------    ------------
total amount           500
```

-----------**i want to display 500 as a total amount**----------

here is foreach loop in my checkout.blade.php file

```
<?php  $items = Session::has('cartS') ? Session::get('cartS') : null; ?>

@foreach($items as $key=>$value)
    <tr>
       <th class="w-50  font-size-14">
          {{ucfirst($value['pname'])}}
       </th>
       <td class="text-right font-size-14">
          {{$value['qnty']}}
       </td>
       <th class="text-right font-size-14">
           {{ $value['qnty'] * $value['price'] }}
       </th>
    </tr>
@endforeach
<h1>your total amount -----------</h1>
```

**Am i doing somthing wrong or i have to display total amount in foreach loop?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to sum the quantity multiplied by the price of each item:

```html
<?php $items = Session::has('cartS') ? Session::get('cartS') : null; ?> 
@php $totalPrice = 0 @endphp 
@foreach($items as $key=>$value)
<tr>
  <th class="w-50  font-size-14">
    {{ucfirst($value['pname'])}}
  </th>
  <td class="text-right font-size-14">
    {{$value['qnty']}}
  </td>
  <th class="text-right font-size-14">
    {{ $value['qnty'] * $value['price'] }}
   @php 
    $totalPrice += $value['qnty'] * $value['price']; 
   @endphp
  </th>
</tr>
@endforeach
<h1>your total amount {{$totalPrice}}</h1>
```